# Pasar arreglo Json a arreglo

Tags: javascript

Tengo este json

```
var response=[{"ts":"2017-01-01T00:00:00+01:00","v":428},{"ts":"2017-01-02T00:00:00+01:00","v":920}]
```

y necesito pasarlo a:

```
["2017-01-01T00:00:00+01:00,428","2017-01-02T00:00:00+01:00,920"]
```

mejor dicho sacarlo de json para un array.

Me podrían ayudar por favor

Comment: Un apunte acerca de una posible confusión de términos: recuerda que [JSON es una notación de datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Lo que tú tienes es una matriz (o arreglo) cuyos elementos son objetos con las propiedades "ts" y "v". Entonces lo que quieres es convertir de matriz de objetos a matriz de cadenas de caracteres. Lo que has puesto abajo, `["2017-01-01T00:00:00+01:00,428", "2017-01-02T00:00:00+01:00,920"]` también es JSON (una notación).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tienes el código:

```js
// Array para convertir el json
var consumo = [];
// Tu Json
var response = [
  {
    "ts": "2017-01-01T00:00:00+01:00",
    "v": 428
  },
  {
    "ts": "2017-01-02T00:00:00+01:00",
    "v": 920
  }
];

// Iterar el JSON, desde 0 a su tamaño
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
  // Se arma la estructura que necesitas 
  var item = response[i]["ts"] + ',' + response[i]["v"];
  // Se inserta el item en el el arreglo de salida
  consumo.push(item);
}

console.log(consumo);
```